# Yum is asking for nonexistent updateinfo.xml hashes on the repodata directory

Tags: yum

Any idea why I need to `"yum clean dbcache metadata"` frequently? I am using centos6.6 and it has the epel repo. It frequently fails to get the packages from the mirrors with a 404 error until I clean the yum again. Below is a part of the log.

```
Trying other mirror.
http://mirrors.syringanetworks.net/fedora-epel/6/x86_64/repodata/3a5d63c8e27b2a5b5bf046c71ec05e3710df642c3e13f6e6354bd2b613f3c7e7-updateinfo.xml.gz: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/3a5d63c8e27b2a5b5bf046c71ec05e3710df642c3e13f6e6354bd2b613f3c7e7-updateinfo.xml.gz: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/3a5d63c8e27b2a5b5bf046c71ec05e3710df642c3e13f6e6354bd2b613f3c7e7-updateinfo.xml.gz: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirrors.tummy.com/pub/fedora.redhat.com/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/3a5d63c8e27b2a5b5bf046c71ec05e3710df642c3e13f6e6354bd2b613f3c7e7-updateinfo.xml.gz: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirrors.kernel.org/fedora-epel/6/x86_64/repodata/3a5d63c8e27b2a5b5bf046c71ec05e3710df642c3e13f6e6354bd2b613f3c7e7-updateinfo.xml.gz: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
```

This is the repolist output

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.solarvps.com
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: mirror.metrocast.net
 * updates: mirror.es.its.nyu.edu
repo id                                                     repo name                                                                                           status
base                                                        CentOS-6 - Base                                                                                      6,518
epel                                                        Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                                      11,745
extras                                                      CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                                       38
updates                                                     CentOS-6 - Updates                                                                                   1,370
repolist: 19,671
```

UPDATES:
I use the chef cookbook to install. https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/yum-epel  .. I don't see any special means used to install the repo.

/var/log/yum.log (shows the plugin that I installed today, after cleaning yum)

```
Jul 07 20:42:05 Installed: wget-1.12-5.el6_6.1.x86_64
Jul 23 17:17:12 Updated: nginx-filesystem-1.0.15-12.el6.noarch
Jul 23 17:17:12 Updated: nginx-1.0.15-12.el6.x86_64
Jul 30 21:25:43 Installed: yum-plugin-security-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch
```

/etc/yum.conf

```
# This file was generated by Chef
# Do NOT modify this file by hand.

[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
debuglevel=2
distroverpkg=centos-release
exactarch=1
gpgcheck=1
installonly_limit=3
keepcache=0
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
obsoletes=1
plugins=1
```

/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo

```
# This file was generated by Chef
# Do NOT modify this file by hand.

[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
enabled=1
failovermethod=priority
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
sslverify=true
```

Comment: Could you add a copy of the `/var/log/yum.log` file along with the called command (ie. `yum update`) and the `yum.conf` and `yum.repos.d` for the epel repositories. BTW, how you enabled the epel repositories?

Comment: @Braiam - updated the logs in the question section